# Php/mysql : How to insert large amount of rows in several tables, in 2 query only

Tags: php, mysql

In my app, I have a job that compute something for the user everyday at exactly midnight UTC. 
I have a row to insert in table A for each user, for this I first compute a string that I concate in à foreach loop, and then I send the whole string to mysqli_query.

```
$q = ‘insert into mb_thing_to_compute values’;
foreach($user as $u) 
{ 
    $q .= ‘’(NULL, {$u[‘ID’]}, $computedStuff),’’;
} 
mysqli_query($q);
```

This way, It seems there is no overhead time, compared to if I sent the insert one by one

Now the problem is that in a second table, I need to send update notification to user, and each notification row has its params in another table. Only mysql know, after the insert, which ID it inserted the rows so I can’t use the first method because I won’t know what are the inserted notification IDs, needed to insert the notification params (each notif has 3 params).

I thought about giving the notifications IDs a php generated ID, with php uniqId function but there is probably a more « clean » to achieve that ?

Comment: I think you should work with mysqli's [begin_transaction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) function , then you can insert your second row with the [insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the latest inserted id .

Comment: What about MySQL triggers?

Comment: I found a way to have the first inserted ID. So I could say ok I have the first ID so I can have ID of the others by just storing their relative index in a php array and do idFirstInserted + index.

Comment: But the problem, imagine the request takes 5mn to complete because there are 500000 rows to insert, if someone else, on another Apache thread, insert in the same table during the request, do you think it will offset the while remaining IDs to be inserted OR the ids are computed before the actual insertion ?